# Ibrowse Erlang HTTP Client Proxy Authentication within a Domain

Tags: security, http, proxy, erlang

My [Ibrowse HTTP Client](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse) is behind a Network and any HTTP request to the outside has to go through a Proxy. Now, Ibrowse has a good example for this. However, i got a little confused. The Proxy behind which i am running the application uses `Domain Authentication` (this Domain is an `Active Directory` kinda setup) whereby usually in a browser we would have to enter settings like this (say the domain is `"kyaug"`),

```
username: kyaug\[YOUR_DOMAIN_USERNAME]
password: [Domain Password]
```

This means that `[YOUR_DOMAIN_USERNAME]` is your Domain Username actually.
Now in the Ibrowse, an example that looks like this comes along:

```
ibrowse:send_req("http://www.erlang.se/", [], get, [],
         [{proxy_user, "XXXXX"},
          {proxy_password, "XXXXX"},
          {proxy_host, "proxy"},
          {proxy_port, 8080}], 5000).
```

Now, lets say that my situation is as follows:

```
Domain:                kyaug
Domain Username:       muzaayj
Proxy Server:          ppi.kyu.co.ug
Proxy Port:            3128
Domain Password:       xxxxx
```

Now, When i try thsi below:

```
Options = [
            {proxy_user, "kyaug\muzaayj"},
            {proxy_password, "My Domain Password"},
            {proxy_host, "ppi.kyu.co.ug"},
            {proxy_port, 3128}
        ],
ibrowse:send_req("http://www.google.com",[],post,Data,Options,infinity).
```

The proxy spits back to me an HTML page informing me that `PROXY_AUTH_REQUIRED` and many other things about its administrators. Now, i have a feeling that its because i am putting the `proxy_user` wrongly. In the above, i am supplying this parameter the way the browsers take it as well, probably behind the scenes, its changed into a different arrangement. Some one assist in how i can correct this. How do browsers send their data to a proxy server for authentication given that the username must be append to the Domain to be used for authentication at the Proxy end ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `{proxy_user, "muzaayj"}` in the options instead of `{proxy_user, "kyaug\muzaayj"}`?

Comment: still can't work. it seems Ibrowse doesnot support NTLM Authentication proxies which require the users' `NT DOMAIN` amongst other parameters

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `{proxy_user, "kyaug\\muzaayj"}`?  A single backslash escapes the `m` back to an `m`, but a double backslash becomes a single backslash in the string.

Comment: still can't work. it seems Ibrowse doesnot support NTLM Authentication proxies which require the users' `NT DOMAIN` amongst other parameters

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ibrowse, but i think that problem in windows authentication method (ofc it depends on AD config, but i suspect that is NTLM Auth) which ibrowse doesnt supprot.